# Displaying data from multiple databases on a webpage

Tags: php, sql, database

I am attempting to create an information screen so that people can have a quick glance at it and be able to read the information from it with ease, this entails displaying certain pieces of data from different *database tables in one database*. Possibly 4 or 5 different tables. these will be then be displayed in a table on the web page for people to see.

What would you recommend is the best way? i could just use a select statement for every piece but if I am taking 3 bits of data from one table and 4 bits from another, surely there is an easier way to gather this data and display it?

Comment: you need to make it much more specific. The question you posed is very vague and opinionated.

Comment: thanks for nothing. i knew my question werent perfect but your answer was hardly useful. the question is vague as im trying to gather as many ideas as possible.

Comment: It is not an answer, just some tips on how you can improve your question in order to make it easier for other users to understand it and help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is truly in entirely separate SQL **databases**, then  you will have to connect to each one, run your query, and disconnect. You can compile all the data using PHP and display it to the user.

If you meant the data is in separate database **tables** (not separate databases) then you can probably compile one query to pull it all -- if the data is related to each other -- or run the 4 or 5 queries needed to pull that data.

You will need to be more specific and share code if you want further help.

Comment: thanks for the response! my bad it was a database with multiple tables. i will try to compile just the one query.